# Delete mistaken post

Tags: support

Can somebody please delete [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10568/calibrating-y-axis-monoprice-wanhao-prusa) as it is useless as it stands, and I am apparently not allowed to do it myself.

Comment: Can you join @0scar in [chat] as he seems to have an answer. I can delete it if you *really* want but it might be better to discuss/explain first to avoid confusion and people taking time to post answers which are then deleted. If you could explain why you think it is useless then it might help others to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to post a duplicate question. You cannot be aware of all questions, and searching sometimes does not bring up a similar question! Hence, other people mark it as duplicate. Having duplicates is very good because some problems can be described differently, this increases the chance a question is found using the search functionality!

Therefore, there is no need to delete it. Also, in your question there where a bunch of side questions, which could be answered while the main problem is described in the duplicate question. Sorry to see you want it to be deleted, there is no need for that.

Please explain why it is useless in your opinion (IMHO I think it is not useless, it is helpful!).